# how to override buildUrl method for rest proxy in sencha touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I need to override the buildUrl method of rest proxy in Sencha Touch 2. The rest GET request will be like that:

```
url:'https://api.abc.com/user/{username}/{password}
```

Where and what should I change to achieve this goal?

and how should I pass the two parameters from controller? [I would like to pass username and password from login controller]

Can anyone please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I have overridden buildUrl for my custom proxy, you can do similar thing:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.proxy.MyAjaxProxy', {
extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
alias: 'proxy.myajaxproxy',
buildUrl: function(request) {
    var me      = this,
        url     = me.callParent(arguments);
    if(!Ext.isEmpty(Helper.apiToken)){
        url = Ext.urlAppend(url, "token="+Helper.apiToken);
    }
    return url;
}
});
```

You can pass username & password in constructor from login controller like this:

```
var myProxy = Ext.create('MyApp.proxy.MyAjaxProxy', {
  username : "a@b.com",
  password : "mypassword"
});
```

and then in buildUrl method you should be able to access these like this `this.config.username`

Comment: What is the 'arguments' you pass to me.callParent? I don't see it defined in your code.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, apparently it is part of JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Answer (score -1):

Check out this **[url](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?179998-How-to-override-buildUrl-Method)**. It covers everything